Python Получение значений из JSON
Есть массив значений:
{
     "errors": null,
     "events": [
         {
             "uuid": "5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb28561-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb28561-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb28562-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb28562-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb28563-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb28563-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb40c00-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb40c00-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb40c01-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb40c01-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb40c02-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb40c02-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb43310-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb43310-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb74050-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb74050-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb74051-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb74051-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true,
                 "highlight": "medium",
                 "highlightedField": "importance"
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb76760-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb76760-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb76761-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb76761-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb851c0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb851c0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb851c1-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb851c1-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true,
                 "highlight": "medium",
                 "highlightedField": "importance"
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb851c2-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb851c2-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb878d0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb878d0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb96330-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb96330-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb96331-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb96331-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true,
                 "highlight": "medium",
                 "highlightedField": "importance"
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb98a40-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb98a40-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb98a41-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb98a41-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         {
             "uuid": "5bb9b150-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb9b150-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true,
                 "highlight": "medium",
                 "highlightedField": "importance"
             }
         }
     ],
     "totalCount": 21,
     "token": "3a31aa69-18e2-4dc9-b16a-a040506b954a"
}

Каким образом из него возможно получить массив по типу
"events" : [
{
"id":"5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16"
},
{
"id":"5bb28561-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16"
}, ....

и т.д. на python

uuid и _meta.id всегда совпадают? Тогда вообще можно просто uuid-ы собрать. А вообще вы бы хоть попытались. Это же обычные словари и списки. Вы же умеете из словаря элементы брать и списки перебирать?

Спасибо, я только познаю азы JSON.

import json

d='''{
     "errors": null,
     "events": [
         {
             "uuid": "5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },
         
         {
             "uuid": "5bb98a41-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb98a41-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true
             }
         },


      .......

         {
             "uuid": "5bb9b150-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
             "_meta": {
                 "id": "5bb9b150-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16",
                 "time": "2024-07-29T13:00:37.0000000Z",
                 "assetIds": null,
                 "site_alias": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_name": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_address": "unknown site_id=null",
                 "site_is_deleted": true,
                 "highlight": "medium",
                 "highlightedField": "importance"
             }
         }
     ],
     "totalCount": 21,
     "token": "3a31aa69-18e2-4dc9-b16a-a040506b954a"
}
'''
j=json.loads(d)
res=[]
for i in j["events"]:
    res.append({'id':i["_meta"]["id"]})
print({"events":res})


{'events': [{'id': '5bb28560-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb28561-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb28562-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb28563-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb40c00-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb40c01-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb40c02-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb43310-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb74050-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb74051-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb76760-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb76761-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb851c0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb851c1-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb851c2-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb878d0-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb96330-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb96331-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb98a40-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb98a41-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}, {'id': '5bb9b150-4daa-11ef-9e78-005056b0ed16'}]}


Спасибо большое! Очень помогло!

JSON очень схож с питоновскими словарями, так что идея работы довольно проста:
import json

events = set()
with open('filename') as f:
    my_json = json.load(f)
for event in my_json['events']:
    events.add({"id": event['_meta']["id"]})


json - это текстовое представление коллекции обычных питоновских списков и словарей в произвольном порядке вложенности. Так что не то что схож, а это они и есть после загрузки - питоновские словари и списки.

ну да, но json существует отдельно от питона, а питоновские словари только в нём. Ну и упорядоченность, на мой взгляд тоже важна (ну и синтаксис чуть-чуть). Так что прям знак равенства яб не ставил, но принцип работы и с тем и с другим, действительно один

Спасибо большое за помощь!
